# Hidden calls to __getattribute__

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a mixin that increments a counter every time a public attribute is read. My implementation below seems to have a hidden increment that I cannot find. From the commented out print statements I can identify it as occurring in the `self._read_count += 1` statement. What am I misunderstanding?

```py
class CounterMixin:
    def __init__(self):
        self._read_count = 0;
        super().__init__();
        
    def _inc_read_count(self):
        # print(f'Pre-inc:  {self._read_count}');
        self._read_count += 1;
        # print(f'Post-inc: {self._read_count}');
    
    @property
    def read_count(self): 
        self._inc_read_count();
        return self._read_count;
        
    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        if attr[0] != '_':
            # print(f'Counting {attr}');
            self._inc_read_count();
        else:
            # print(f'Not counting {attr}');
            pass;
        return super().__getattribute__(attr);


class Bar(CounterMixin):
    pass

foo = Bar();
print(foo.read_count);
print('---');
foo.x = 1;
print(foo.read_count);
print('---');
_ = foo.x;
print(foo.read_count);
```

Expected output:

```
1
---
2
---
4
```

Actual output:

```
2
---
4
---
7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're incrementing `self._read_count` twice when you access `read_count`, once in `__getattribute__` and once in the property getter.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!